Unset API Management service api version enforcement
I have an Azure API Management Service that has the Minimum API version set to 2018-01-01 and I'd like to unset this and change the Enforce minumum API version to No.
This is how it is currently set:

You'll notice these are greyed out and I've been able to change the Minimum API version via the rest API.
However, I want to set Enforce minumum API version to No. I'm unable to find a way to do this through the Rest API however. I'm also unfortunately unable to use the Azure CLI right now - though this is an option in future.
A note to say I am aware of changes specifying that we need to use the minimum set to 2019-12-01. While I'm putting in steps to meet that requirement I'm in need of a "right-now" fix.
Can anyone tell me how to change this setting via Rest API or CLI?

Is CLI works for you? @0Neji

Hi @Jahnavi, I'm still without CLI access (as per original post). I ended up setting this with the REST API, the trick was getting the right command and setting it to null was the key. If you want to update your answer to reflect that I'll award your answer.

Hi @0Neji Good to know that your issue got resolved with the REST API approach as well. May I know what update you want me to do in the answer exactly!


How to change this setting via Rest API or CLI?

You can achieve it using az apim update CLI command with --set argument as shown in the below way.
az apim update -n newapimjah -g Jahnavi --set apiVersionConstraint.minApiVersion=null

Output:

Also, check here in MSDoc to achieve it using REST API.
